# Cannot undo text-decoration for child-elements

Tags: html, css

Say you have this html:

```
<a href="#">
    This is underlined
    <span>
        This isn't.
    </span>
</a>
```

And this css:

```
a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline; /* I know, this is enabled by default. */
}

a:hover span {
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

Why does the a > span element still has an underline. I'm pretty sure you should actually have undone the decoration by using 'none'. I know that you can achieve the result I want by using this:

```
<a href="#">
    <span class="underlined">
        This is underlined
    </span>
    <span>
        This isn't.
    </span>
</a>
```

plus this css:

```
a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover span.underlined {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

But... it just doesn't make sense to me why you can't unset the text-decoration of a child-element.
So, why...?

**Edit: Inline-blocks**

According to @amosrivera, it does work when you use inline-block. I can confirm this to work in Safari and Chrome!

```
a:hover span{
    text-decoration:none;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

As mentioned, this works for Safari and Chrome, but not for Firefox. The following solution works for Firefox, but not for Safari and Chrome...

```
a:hover span{
    text-decoration:none;
    display:block;
}
```

Little table:

```
    CSS-Rule            |    Webkit    |    Firefox    |    Opera    |    IE    
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
display: block;         |       x      |               |      ?      |     ?    
display: inline-block;  |              |       x       |      ?      |     ?
```

Comment: IE7, works without anything, IE8 and Opera both work with inline-block. FF3.6/4 is wrong, it explicitly says in the [text-decoration definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#propdef-text-decoration) "_User agents must not render these text decorations on content that is not text. For example, images and inline blocks must not be underlined._"

Answer (score 42):

It has to do with the fact that `span` is an inline element. Try this:

```
a span{
    text-decoration:none;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

**Online demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/yffXp/

**UPDATE**

In FF (4?) only **display:block** works (which at the same time in webkit doesn't), causes line break.

**UPDATE 2** (hack?)

```
a span{
    display:inline-block;
    background:#fff;
    line-height:1.1em;
}
```

Overlaying the white background over the border is not pretty but it seems to do it. It works in every browser other than `IE 6,7`

**Online demo:**    http://jsfiddle.net/yffXp/6/

Comment: That is interesting. Do you know why it being an inline element is a factor?

Comment: The online demo shows everything underlined for me (FF 4). If I set it to `display: block;` the underline is gone as expected.

Comment: Not still underlined in Chrome 10.

Comment: @steve you're right, it doesnt work on ff4, just with display:block

Comment: @Moses, good question. And why display:block doesn't work, while inline-block does work. Doesn't make sense to me either...

Comment: Edit: display:block doesn't work in Webkit, while it does work in Firefox. Inline-block doesn't work in Firefox, while it does work in Safari.

Comment: Well, this got me curious, although i did not find an explanation, i tried this hack (working ff and chrome) let me know: http://jsfiddle.net/yffXp/2/

Comment: I should point out that inline elements cannot be parents of block elements. So having an anchor (implicitly inline) with a nested span (explicitly block) is against the spec. Apparently, though, nesting an inline-block inside an inline element is just fine.

Comment: span is by default inline **not  block** "These elements define content to be inline (SPAN)" http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html

Comment: That last demo isn't really a solution. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/yffXp/8/

Comment: @Moses you're quite right about nesting block level elements inside  inline ones, but changing a CSS display not change the actual element properties so nesting a *inline* `span` with `display:block` inside an *inline* `a` is perfectly OK it will validate however you will then get the line breaks ;)

Comment: @thirtydot yeah, thats why i stated "Overlaying the white background over the border is not pretty" ;)

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that if the parent is also `display: flex` the child will always get an underline regardless of its `display` property.

Answer (score 15):

There might be some incredibly zany cross-browser way to do it, but I'd just go with this (a variation of the solution in your question), for the sake of sanity:

It just works: http://jsfiddle.net/KrepM/1/

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#">
    <span>This is underlined</span>
    This isn't.
</a>
```

**CSS:**

```
a:hover {
    text-decoration: none
}

a:hover span {
    text-decoration: underline
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work if it reverse `a:hover underline` and the child is none

Answer (score 2):

As a solution, I'd use @thirtydot's one, but as far as the problem is concerned, I think you are looking at it the wrong way.

Check the following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeroen/yffXp/10/): As you can see the non-decorated part is not decorated with the colour given; what you are seeing is the colour of it´s parent that extends to the end of the element (as spaces in an `a` are underlined as well). So the browser is really doing what you are telling it to do, you just don´t see it.

As a reference, compare the previous fiddle with [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/jeroen/yffXp/12/). And guess what happens when you change the colour of the `span` to the [background colour](http://jsfiddle.net/jeroen/yffXp/13/)...

Comment: This is true, the underlining is propagating to the inline child element (anonymous or otherwise), like color does - but then the recs (there's a link in a comment to the OP) specifically state the handling of underlining on inline-blocks and images (it shouldn't propagate!) so I'd say that those browsers not handling the inline-block solution here are being naughty ;)

Answer (score 1):

Caught that problem when I used a class for my link.

```
<a href="#close" class="close">&times;</a>
```

If I used .close in my css chrome and safari kept underlining the link. When I added a tag before class name everything started working fine.

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
a.close {
    color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[@amosrivera's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5434918/5500690) helped me out but it wasn't enough:

I had the following:

```html
<p>
    some text
</p>
```

Which was getting underlined from a distant ancestor element's `<a>` element. Even after directly selecting the `<p>` element and applying `text-decoration: none`, it still had underlines. So I had to do the following:

1. Wrap all text in a span:

   ```html
   <p>
       <span>some text</span>
   </p>
   ```
2. *Then* I could use [@amosrivera's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5434918/5500690):

   ```css
   span {
       display: inline-block;
   }
   ```

I apparently don't even need `text-decoration: none`!

Answer (score 0):

The text-decoration will propagate to all elements (similar to color) that are not `display: block` or `inline-block` (even flex/grid layouts are affected).

But there's a simple trick to undo text-decoration if it has certain nested elements using the has selector:

```css
a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
a:hover:has(span) {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

This will disable text-decoration for the parent if it has a certain child element.

Now I know this isn't exactly the scenario described above.
For that specific case there's indeed no alternative than using `block`.

Answer (score -1):

I came across this problem today, but for pseudo elements, which amounts to the same situation and I was able to find a solution. Set `overflow:hidden;` on the child element. Then set your height of the child element slightly smaller than the height for the rest of the link. You'll have to play with the height a few times to get it just right, but eventually you should be able to make the underline disappear.