# Remove :hover on :after elements

Tags: css

I'm trying to remove the `:hover` behaviour in an `:after` pseudoselector for a link. But I think that it's not possible.

```css
a {
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #666;
  text-decoration: none
}

a:after {
  content: "·";
  margin: 0 2px 0 6px
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline
}

a:hover:after {
  text-decoration: none
}
```

```html
<a href="#">test</a>
<a href="#">test</a>
<a href="#">test</a>
```

Checkout the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3N9vs/).

Is it possible?

Answer (score 6):

You need to give the `:after` psuedo element `position:absolute;` and give it `margin` to shift it. Also the anchor requires `display:inline-block;` in order for the `:after` content to appear correctly.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/ECFBR/

Comment: This doesn't make any difference in, for example, IE9.

Comment: You're right, seems to work in Chrome and Firefox but not IE. Maybe there isn't a totally CSS based solution to this problem

Comment: I don't think there is. I'm reminded of this previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434819/cannot-undo-text-decoration-for-child-elements

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way to handle this is to wrap a `span` around the text in each link:

```
<a href="#"><span>test</span></a>
```

On `:hover` only the `span` is given `text-decoration: underline`:

```
a:hover span {text-decoration: underline}
```

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/3N9vs/27/

A similar older question: [Cannot undo text-decoration for child-elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434819/cannot-undo-text-decoration-for-child-elements)
Also relevant: [CSS text-decoration property cannot be overridden by child element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481318/css-text-decoration-property-cannot-be-overridden-by-child-element/4481356#4481356)

Comment: The propagation of text decorations mentioned in my answer applies to pseudo-elements as well, since the boxes they generate are children of the `a` element's box. Not too sure why Josh's solution works in Chrome and Firefox, though.