# Selectively stopping text-decoration: underline on children of a link tag

Tags: html, css

Does anybody know if it's possible to prevent underlining on the child of an  tag, while underlining the rest of the tag's contents?

Here's an example - you can see this working on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andfinally/ygXy6/2/). I've tried everything I can think of, but the text underlining continues to be applied to all the text inside the link. I'm viewing on Chrome, but I'm sure this applies to all browsers.

```
a {
    font-size: 32px;           
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

a div {
    color: pink;
}

a:hover div,
a:active div,
a:focus div {
    text-decoration: none !important;
}​

<a href="http://news.bbc.co.uk">
<div class="inner">I don't want this bit underlined on hover. What's the big deal?</div>
This bit should be underlined on hover. Underlining here is fine. I have no objections to underlinining in this bit.
</a>​
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read this similar answer and its links for more information: [Remove :hover on :after elemets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122213/remove-hover-on-after-elemets/10122632#10122632)

http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/ygXy6/4/

**CSS:**

```css
a {
    font-size: 32px;           
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover span {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<a href="http://news.bbc.co.uk">
    <div class="inner">I don't want this bit underlined on hover. What's the big deal?</div>
    <span>This bit should be underlined on hover. Underlining here is fine. I have no objections to underlinining in this bit.</span>
</a>​
```

Comment: Cant it be done without using span inside?? I mean is there any way to skip the first child by taking the assigned style??

Comment: @SowmyaShivaram: As far as I know, not when it comes to `text-decoration`. It's explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481318/css-text-decoration-property-cannot-be-overridden-by-child-element/4481356#4481356

Comment: ya I know that. I just asked if in case you know the way to do it. thats it

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the answers guys, I'll use this method.